# 'enable wireless' not showing in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wireless

I have gone through other posts to solve the problem, but it seems bit difficult to fix it. I have ubuntu 12.10 on HP notebook. 
I don't see 'enable wireless' option on the control panel.
Could someone guide me through this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**1.** First thing to check is you didn't disable wireless with your keyboard (more common than you might think). If you have a networking key on your keyboard see if that fixes it.

**2.** If not, do you see the network monitor applet in the top bar, where the battery icon etc. are? There should be a dropdown menu with an "enable wireless" setting or something similar. Eg in Gnome Shell:

[image: Enable wireless setting in Gnome Shell]

**3.** In the System Settings, you should see "Network" in the "Hardware" section. From there you should be able to select Wireless settings and turn on networking. Again, this is how mine looks in Gnome Shell (yours might be slightly different if you're using Unity):

[image: Enabling wireless in Gnome Shell]

**4.** You can also use the terminal, if you're comfortable with that. First you need the name of your connection, probably 'wlan0' but sometimes 'eth1'. Run `ifconfig` and you should see a number of entries listed. Then to turn the wireless on, run `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up`, or `sudo ifconfig eth1 up`.

**5.** If none of those work, it may be that you don't have the correct drivers installed. Afaik, HP notebooks are very well supported, so I doubt it is a driver issue. Nevertheless, you can check your wireless card is activated and such using the command `sudo lshw -C network` [as described here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/internet/C/troubleshooting-wireless.html). Look for the one with `description: Wireless interface` and make see if the line `configuration:` has a driver listed. If you need a driver, check "Additional Drivers" under "Hardware" in System Settings.